# How to handle double-click in MMC

Tags: c#, .net, mmc

I have an MmcListView in a custom MMC snap-in I'm developing. I see that there are some standard event handlers for Refresh, Actions, etc. but how do I handle a double-click? Right now, my users have to right-click a result node and click an action. It would make a lot of sense if they could just double-click a node.